# Calculation of Number Density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Number density equation is given by

$ n= \dfrac{(N_A)\rho}{M} $

where
$ N_A =6.023\times10^{23} mol^{-1} $

$ \rho=8.02\ g/cm^3 $(at 1500 degree celsius.)

$M=63.546*1.6605\times10^{-24} g$

Whats wrong with this values? I am failed to calculate number density.

Answer (score 1):

In your formula $M$ is the molar mass given in $g \,\text{mol}^{-1}$ so for your compound $M=63.546 \,g \,\text{mol}^{-1}$ and the density in atoms per cubic centimeter will be $n=7.6 \cdot 10^{22}$$\text{cm}^{-3}$.